Accessing public property using reflection using GetProperty c#
I am currently working on a  Blazor project in .NET8 and are having some issues trying to access a public property at runtime using reflection.
Issue:
I have an array of objects[] at runtime which I cant access the properties value i need once I have drilled down the array to the type using reflection.
I have tried this so far which I am able to see the properties and the types values but cant access them.
            //Have to use reflection as we don't now the type at compile time
            var type = obj[i].GetType();

            //I can see all of the public properties in this array 
            object[] PropertyInfo = type.GetProperties();

            //but when I try and access one of the properties, I get null
            var property = type.GetProperty("Name");

            //The name should be accessable here??
            var name = property.GetValue(obj[i]);

Public Model:
public class MyClass
{
    public int Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}`

Any help or guidance would be very welcomed as I thought it was due to the property not being public but it actually is.
Thanks in advance for any pointers on this one

Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f6hioF

What exactly is null? The property object or the name value? Btw., the other line should read: PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

so the property returns System.String name then call property.GetValue(obj[i]); the value is null.

if you inspect obj[i] in the debugger, does its property Name have a value other than null?

Are you building your Blazor app using WebAssembly AOT compilation as shown in e.g. ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly build tools and ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation?

If you are using Native AOT, see NET8 NativeAOT: Type.GetProperties() doesn't work for some types but does for others! why?.  Or modify your design so you don't need late-bound reflection.

My guess is your problem is i.  You aren't showing the loop or how your using it.
Here's a Blazor demo page based on your code that works.  Note I use @foreach that defines a local copy of obj in the lowered code.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@foreach(var obj in _list)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty("Name");
    var value = property?.GetValue(obj);
        <div>Type: @type.Name - Value: @value  </div>
}

@code {
    private object[] _list = { 
        new MyClass() { Name="Fred",  Address = 1 }, 
        new MyClass1() { Name="Joe",  Address = 2 },
    };

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Address { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass1
    {
        public int Address { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}


